# Why can't I SSH into virtual machine?

Tags: ssh, virtualbox

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 as host. Virtual machine is Ubuntu 20.04 with a bridged adapter.

When I SSH into host machine from VM, everything goes right. But when I try SSH in reverse(from host into VM) it gives an error saying `Connection refused`.

I have tried opening the ports, but nothing has worked. I am suspecting it is an issue or restriction with the VM.

Comment: "*connection refused*" suggests that the ssh server in your VM Guest is not running.

Comment: Generally this happens if: (1) there is no SSH Server listening for connections (2) `ufw` is not permitting the connection through (3) the IP has been recycled and your host sees a different SSH fingerprint, warns you that something has changed, and refuses to let you connect. Could you [edit] your question to include the complete error message? 

Comment: You weren't specific as to what Ubuntu 20.04 LTS product you're talking about, desktop installs for example include only the SSH client (not server), as most desktop users only `ssh` to other machines

Comment: While on the vm try `ssh localhost`. If you can't do that, you likely won't get external connections. This is a good way to test if ssh is working at all.